# Is there a weak strong regularity lemma?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

A famous strengthening of Szemerédi's regularity lemma, due to Alon, Fischer, Krivelevich and Szegedy, allows one to partition a graph into a bounded number of pieces in such a way that not only are almost all pairs regular, but the degree of regularity of the pairs is allowed to depend, however you like, on the number of pieces. Unfortunately, the bound for this lemma is very bad indeeed: it is a wowzer function, and that has been shown to be necessary by Conlon and Fox, and independently by Kalyasundaram and Shapira.

With the usual notion of regularity, one can get a much better bound if instead of partitioning the whole graph, one just wants a single regular pair. Roughly speaking, if you start with a pair that is not regular, you can drop down to a denser subgraph, and you keep doing that until you arrive at a subgraph that is regular.

I would like to know what is known about the situation where you just want a single regular pair $(A,B)$ (the sense in which the statement is weak) but you want the degree of regularity of that pair to depend on the densities of $A$ and $B$ (the sense in which the statement is strong). Is there a reference for this, and what kind of bound can one hope for?

Comment: Some partial answer can be found in my paper with Jacob Fox (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.4829.pdf). Here we prove two things: firstly, we show a wowzer-type lower bound for the strong regularity lemma, independently of Kalayanasundaram and Shapira (in fact, the bound is somewhat better), and we also prove a 'strong weak' regularity lemma which suffices for applications to induced removal and its relatives. However, this still gives a tower-type bound, so it's likely not as strong as you would like.

Comment: Thank you for that -- and I've updated the post to mention that you and Jacob also proved the lower bound for the strong regularity lemma.

Comment: "but the degree of regularity of the pairs is allowed to depend, however you like, on the number of pieces" no. you have a partition $A$ with $k$ pieces and then a refinement $B$ of $A$ with $kl$ pieces. The degree of regularity of the pairs in $B$ just depends on $k$ and has nothing to do with $l$.